# How to prevent Redis TTL from renewing?

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, ttl

I am working on a bug for a Spring service that uses Redis to cache the results of a query for 30 minutes. *The TTL should **only** be set when it is first saved in the cache and the time should NOT be renewed by subsequent queries.* This is the default behavior for Redis.

And yet I have found that the source of the bug is that every call to the cache renews the TTL. It is particularly puzzling that the default behavior is not being implemented because there is remarkably little Redis configuration in the project.

The only Redis configuration is in the Pojo being cached which is annotated with -

`@RedisHash(value = "POJO_NAME", timeToLive = 1800)`

The only other Redis config are some values set in the application.yml

```
redis:
    service:
      name: project-cache
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
    jedis:
      pool:
        max-total: 16
        max-idle: 8
        min-idle: 4
    timeout: 250
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
      <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```